# How to check if 2 CollisionObjects can collide?

Tags: godot

let's say I have `Obj_A` (RigidBody2D) & `Obj_B` (RigidBody2D)
I want to check if these 2 **CAN** collide

so far my idea is checking the mutual layers in both their `collision_mask` & `collision_layer`

the problem I'm facing is that `Obj_A.collision_mask` & (`collision_layer`) does not return an array of the layers and instead returns [binary](https://godotengine.org/qa/97172/how-can-i-get-the-collision-layer-or-mask-of-a-body)

so is there any inbuilt function to check for it?
or is there some different approach altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bitwise operations.

Imagine the operation you want, but for a single bit. So a `bool`. And we want to get `true` when they are both `true`. And `false` otherwise. We write a truth table for that if we want to:

| "collision_mask" | "collision_layer" | desired result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `false` | `false` | `false` |
| `false` | `true` | `false` |
| `true` | `false` | `false` |
| `true` | `true` | `true` |

*I'm writing "collision_mask" and "collision_layer" in quotes here as reminder that this is an hypothetical in which they are `bool`, accounting for only one possible layer (bit).*

We observe from the table that, of course, the operation we want is conjunction (`and`).

Now, the bitwise conjunction operator is `&`. It works with `int`s and will perform the operation… *bitwise*. For example:

```
var a := 0b1100 # Binary literal for 12
var b := 0b1010 # Binary literal for 10
var c := 0b1000 # Binary literal for  8
print (c == a & b) # true
```

As you can see, it does not give you a `true` or `false` value. Instead what we get is an `int` where each bit is the result of doing the operation on the bits that are on the same position on the inputs.

In consequence, when we use `&`, if the inputs have bits that are <strike>`true`</strike> `1` on the same position, the bit on that same position but on the result will also be <strike>`true`</strike> `1`.

Say that in negative terms: if none of bits of the inputs are <strike>`true`</strike> `1` on the same position, then all the bits on the result will be <strike>`false`</strike> `0`.

*And we can check that!*

Ergo:

```
if (Obj_A.collision_mask & Obj_B.collision_layer) == 0:
    # no possible collision
    pass
```

Or, you know, negate it:

```
if (Obj_A.collision_mask & Obj_B.collision_layer) != 0:
    # possible collision
    pass
```

And, yes, check both ways:

```
if (
    (Obj_A.collision_mask & Obj_B.collision_layer) != 0
    and (Obj_A.collision_layer & Obj_B.collision_mask) != 0
):
    # possible collision
    pass
```

---

For reference these are the bitwise operators in GDScript:

| operation | bool | alternative | bitwise |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| negation | `not` | `!` | `~` |
| conjunction | `and` | `&&` | `&` |
| disjunction | `or` | `||` | `|` |
| exclusive disjunction |  |  | `^` |

Note that there is a bitwise exclusive disjunction operator (`^`), but not a corresponding `bool` operator (there is no `xor` operator).

*I also want to mention that GDScript has bit shifting operators: `<<` and `>>`.*

---

If you rather not use bitwise operators, you can instead use `get_collision_layer_bit` and `get_collision_mask_bit`. With knowledge that there are 32 possible layers, you can do this:

```
var can_collide := false
for layer in 32:
    if Obj_A.get_collision_mask_bit(layer) and Obj_B.get_collision_layer_bit(layer):
        can_collide = true

if can_collide:
    # possible collision
    pass
```

That is the same logic that we are executing with the bitwise operations. Except much less succinct and with worse performance.

---

Also for reference, this is `get_collision_mask_bit` is implemented:

```
bool CollisionObject::get_collision_mask_bit(int p_bit) const {
    ERR_FAIL_INDEX_V_MSG(p_bit, 32, false, "Collision mask bit must be between 0 and 31 inclusive.");
    return get_collision_mask() & (1 << p_bit);
}
```

Which you could write in GDScript like this:

```
func get_collision_mask_bit(bit:int) -> bool:
    if bit >= 32:
        push_error("Collision mask bit must be between 0 and 31 inclusive.")
        return

    return 0 != collision_mask & (1 << bit)
```

I bring this up to highlight that these are built ontop of the bitwise operators, and not the other way around.

*It is also an example of use of a bit shift operator.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out, turns out it was simpler than I thought :P

```
func will_collide(obj1,obj2):
    return (obj1.collision_layer & obj2.collision_mask) || (obj1.collision_layer & obj2.collision_mask)
```